# Clear form field after error is encountered

Tags: react-native, formik

On my react native form, after wrong input values are inputted into the field, I'd have to return to the previous page, and then back to the form page before my submit can work.

Typing data in the input field and submitting doesn't do anything at all until the process described above has been done. No errors, no progress.

I'd want immediately an error occurs, for my submit button to still be able to process data from the input fields.

Below is what my submit Handler looks like:

```
 const submitHandler = async (values, actions) => {
    const {name, password} = values
    const data = {
      username: name,
      password: password,
    };
    console.log("data", data);
      await login(data, navigation.navigate, actions)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a ref for your Textinput then call clear text on that ref

```js
const inputRef = useRef(null)

const clearText = ()=> inputRef.current.clear();

     <TextInput
        name="last_name"
        placeholder="Last name"
        ref={inputRef}
      />
```